# React: this.setState not resetting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data I'm distilling to render, essentially I'd like to have a checkbox to reset the state and DOM as it would when the page loads.

Initially I had a selected property on the state and a conditional to make sure it was working. That worked. But I can't get it to work, what am I missing?

**UPDATE May 9th 2018**

As Jay suggested below I am going to put the whole module in a snippet and focus on the parts which are the crux of the question/problem,

The whole module is in a snippet below...

I have a component that displays an array of objects, and each object is getting distilled into its own card. Below is a screenshot for clarity.

[image]

Here is my method in my component:

```
handleReset() {
    this.setState({
      data: this.props.data,
    });
  }
```

And this is the JSX which is being rendered.

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.handleReset} />
  <b>reset</b>
</label>
```

With some time to think about this I realize that my handeReset is not doing anything is probably because it is just rendering the state as it is now. So how my question is how do you go back to the way the UI looked initially? Pre sorting?

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  Card,
  Select,
  Segment,
  Container,
  Divider,
  Grid,
  Header,
  Image
} from 'semantic-ui-react';
import '../css/app.css';

class FilterOptions extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
      priority: '',
      category: '',
      selected: false,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
  }

  handleReset() {
    this.setState({
      data: this.state.data,
    });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    var val = e.target.value;
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      this.setState({
        priority: val
      });
    } else if (isNaN(val)) {
      this.setState({
        category: val
      });
    }
    this.props.changeOption(val);
  }

  render() {
    var reset;
    if (!this.state.data) {
      reset = 'reset';
    } else {
      reset = 'not reset';
    }
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      h5 > By category < /h5> <
      label >
      <
      input type = "checkbox"
      onChange = {
        this.handleReset
      }
      />
      reset {
        reset
      } <
      /label> <
      h5 > By category < /h5> <
      ul >
      <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "cat1"
      checked = {
        this.state.category === 'cat1'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      cat1 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "cat2"
      checked = {
        this.state.category === 'cat2'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      cat2 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "cat3"
      checked = {
        this.state.category === 'cat3'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      cat3 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      /ul> <
      h5 > By priority < /h5> <
      ul >
      <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "1"
      checked = {
        this.state.priority === '1'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      1 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "2"
      checked = {
        this.state.priority === '2'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      2 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "3"
      checked = {
        this.state.priority === '3'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      3 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      li >
      <
      label >
      <
      input type = "radio"
      value = "4"
      checked = {
        this.state.priority === '4'
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      />
      4 <
      /label> <
      /li> <
      /ul> {
        /*<h5>By Color</h5>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" value="Orange" checked={this.state.color === 'Orange'} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                          <div className="circle orange-filter-bg" />
                        </label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" value="Green" checked={this.state.color === 'Green'} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                          <div className="circle green-filter-bg" />
                        </label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" value="Blue" checked={this.state.color === 'Blue'} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                          <div className="circle blue-filter-bg" />
                        </label>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" value="Purple" checked={this.state.color === 'Purple'} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                          <div className="circle purple-filter-bg" />
                        </label>
                      </li>
                    </ul>*/
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

function FilterUsers(props) {
  return ( <
    Container >
    <
    br / >
    <
    br / >
    <
    Grid columns = {
      3
    }
    doubling stackable > {
      props.data.map((user /* leveraging arrow functions implicit return */ ) => ( <
        Grid.Column key = {
          user.name
        } >
        <
        Segment className = {
          `priority${user.priority}`
        } >
        <
        Card >
        <
        Card.Content >
        <
        Card.Header >
        <
        h2 > name: {
          user.name
        } < /h2> <
        /Card.Header> <
        Card.Meta >
        <
        span className = "card__age" > age: {
          user.age
        } < /span> <
        /Card.Meta> <
        Card.Description > priority: {
          user.priority
        } < /Card.Description> <
        Card.Description className = "card__catergory" > category: {
          user.category
        } < /Card.Description> <
        /Card.Content> <
        /Card> <
        /Segment> <
        /Grid.Column>
      ))
    } <
    /Grid> <
    /Container>
  );
}

export default class SortAndFilterForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
      priority: '',
      category: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(val) {
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
      this.setState({
        priority: val
      });
      var filteredByPriority = this.props.data.filter(function(item) {
        return parseInt(item.priority) === parseInt(val);
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        category: val
      });
      var filteredByPriority = this.props.data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.category === val;
      });
      this.setState({
        category: val
      });
    }

    console.log('filteredByPriority', filteredByPriority);
    this.setState({
      data: filteredByPriority
    });
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      Container >
      <
      h1 > Sorts < /h1> <
      FilterOptions data = {
        this.state.data
      }
      changeOption = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      /> <
      FilterUsers data = {
        this.state.data
      }
      /> <
      /Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Judging by the large amount of commented out code above, I’m guessing you just copy-pasted your whole module in here.  You might consider stripping out some of the complexity to focus on the issue at hand.  Either that or you can build UP a minimal test case.  That process usually leads me directly to what I was doing wrong but even if it doesn’t, it will be a lot easier for US to help you.

Comment: You are so right! I guess I thought the problem TO ME seemed so easy to understand, I should have realized obviously folks aren't as familiar.
Anywho, I have refactored and updated my question! Thanks @JayAllen!!!

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing the issue is here:

```
handleReset() {
  this.setState({
    data: this.state.data,
  });
}
```

where you set the `state.data` to `state.data`, which unsurprisingly doesn't change anything.  I imagine you want to do:

```
handleReset() {
  this.setState({
    data: this.props.data,
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks pal, but that didn't do the trick. I actually thought once you kindly pointed that out that was it...

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Did anything change after you tried this solution? That's the problem I see when looking at your code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your HandleReset() method should be setting everything in state as it was at the start:

```
this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
      priority: '',
      category: '',
    };
```

And your cards are rendered with props.data.map meaning they would remain unaffected with changes in state. You should use data from state to render them out.

Comment: Thanks! That has the effect of clearing out the selections of the current radio button selections, but does not reset the UI i.e. cards

Comment: Updated my answer with what I think is causing cards to remain unchanged

Comment: Great, so being my `FilterUsers` component is a Functional component does that mean I should change it to a class component? Because right now the only way data is obtained is through props.

Comment: Not really, your FilterUsers component should just accept data. don't make it accept props / state. That should be handled by the code that uses this component.

Comment: function FilterUsers(data) {
  return ( <
    Container >
      data.map((user /* leveraging arrow functions implicit return */ ) =>

Comment: Hard to format in a comment @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz hope it makes sense. Just replaced the accepted parameter to be data instead of props.data

Comment: Thank you but now I am getting `data.map is not a function`

Comment: And this is how  `FilterUsers` looks/renders in `SortAndFilterForm` component
`<FilterUsers data={this.state.data} />`

Comment: Yep that's what I had in mind,how filterUsers is set. The error could be because it may not be able to identify data to be array to have map. May be try to set type explicitly or to any

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz did that help?

Comment: Sorry I should have asked...did you mean with `Proptypes`?

Comment: <FilterUsers data={this.state.data} /> should be as it is and I wanted to know if function FilterUsers(props: any) { would fix the error "data.map is not a function" Of course, we shouldn't be using any, this is just to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would turn `FilterOptions` into a purely functional component (e.g accepts only `props`, has no `constructor`, no `state`, move `handleReset` and `handleChange` upwards to `SortAndFilterForm` and pass them back down via props).

In `SortAndFilterForm`'s `constructor()`, I would store a *copy* of its initial state `data` element (which has been passed to it as `props.data` from something else) as a state variable (n.b. `Object.assign` creates a shallow shallow copy which seems like it should work here but it depends on the contents and how you mutate them elsewhere):

```
this.state = {
  data: props.data,
  initData: Object.assign({}, props.data),
  priority: '',
  category: ''
}
```

The `handleReset` method in `SortAndFilterForm`'s would then look like this:

```
handleReset() {
  this.setState({
    data: Object.assign({}, this.state.initData)
  })
}
```

You will of course need to bind that in `SortAndFilterForm`'s `constructor()`:

```
this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this)
```

...and pass it down to `FilterOptions`:

```
    <FilterOptions
        data={this.state.data}
        changeOption={this.handleChange}
        resetOption={this.handleReset}   />
```

I believe all of the above should take care of your problem.